# How to interpret forecast output in words

Tags: forecasting, prediction-interval

May I ask you guys regarding `forecast` in R?

How should I interpret this graph? Please describe it in easy-understandable words.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ets()` (which stands for "Error-Trend-Seasonality" and implements a state space formulation of standard exponential smoothing algorithms) has fit a model with *a*dditive error, *n*o trend and *n*o seasonality (A,N,N). That is: it believes your observations are iid and there is essentially no structure to them, apart from a constant expectation and variance.

The future expected value is about 5000, for each future time point. We expect 80% of future observations to lie in the interval [1700,9200], and 95% in [-50,11100]; the last two are [prediction-interval](/questions/tagged/prediction-interval)s. All numbers read off the graph, of course.

You might profit from reading an introductory forecasting testbook. I recommend the excellent free online book [*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* (2nd ed.) by Athanasopoulos & Hyndman](https://otexts.org/fpp2/).